# Is it true that for each bounded continuous function we can find a set of analytic functions to uniformly converge it?

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that for each bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$, we can find a set of analytic functions $g_i:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R, i=1,2,...$ such that $g_i$ uniformly converges to $f$ ?

Comment: Actually it's true for any continuous functions, it's a classic result I think due to Carleman. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/26243/asymptotic-approximation-of-x-alpha-by-entire-functions/26290#26290

Answer (score 15):

Convolve it with narrower and narrower Gauss kernels.

Comment: Convolutions are smooth, but why analytic?

Comment: Because the Gauss kernel is.

Comment: But the convolution with a gauss kernel is not defined for all continuous functions

Comment: For bounded function it is well defined and real analytic indeed.

Comment: Oh "bounded" sorry

Comment: I'm secretly solving the heat equation with the given function as the initial data.

Comment: Don't you need *uniformly* continuous functions to get *uniform* convergence?

Comment: Good point: maybe you can make the width of the kernel depend on the modulus of continuity, but I'm not entirely sure that works.

Answer (score 8):

In the paper

- MR0098847 (20 #5299)
  Grauert, Hans:
  On Levi's problem and the imbedding of real-analytic manifolds. 
  Ann. of Math. (2) 68 1958 460–472.

it is proved (Proposition 8) that real analytic functions are dense in continuous functions for the Whitney $C^0$-topology, for any paracompact real analytic manifold. The sup-norm gives a coarser topology, so this also follows.