# Asymptotic behavior of gradient descent on a smooth, convex, non-negative function with no finite minimum

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, asymptotics, convex-optimization

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a  function which is convex and smooth (*i.e.*, in $C^{\infty}$). If $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is the (global) minimum of $f$, it is [well known](https://rkganti.wordpress.com/2015/08/21/convergence-rate-of-gradient-descent-algorithm/) that gradient descent with a (sufficiently small) fixed step size $\eta$,
$$ x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \eta \nabla f(x_n), $$
converges to the global minimum $x_n \rightarrow x^*$.

**Question**: What is the asymptotic behavior of gradient descent when a finite minimizer $x^*$ does not exist (*i.e.*, when $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \nabla f(x)\neq 0$)?

My guess is that $x_n/||x_n||$ should converge to some finite solution, but I could not find a proof. Or perhaps there is some counter-example to this claim?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function $f(x)=atan2(x(1),x(2))$ is a counterexample. You can also find a continuous counterexample by changing this function locally at the half line of discontinuity.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this function appears to be non-convex.

Comment: Ok then take $f(x)=ax(1)^2-x(2)$ with $a>\eta^{-1}$ instead.

Comment: This function can be negative, and also this is not a counter-example since $ x_n / || x_n ||$ converges to $(0,1)$ or $(0,-1)$.

Comment: Can you check $f(x)=e^{x(1)}+x(1)^2x(2)^2$?

Comment: $x_n / || x_n || $ converges to $(-1,0)$ .

Comment: Btw, the two variable function $f(x,y)=e^x + x^2y^2$ is not convex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are simple counterexamples of the form $f(x,y)=\phi(x)+\psi(y)$ (here $x$ and $y$ denote real variables),  where $\phi$ and $\psi$ are smooth, positive, decreasing, strictly convex functions.

The idea is that, $-\psi'(x)$ and $-\phi'(x)$ being positive decreasing functions, is not an obstruction for their ratio to oscillate between arbitrarily large and small values, on arbitrarily large intervals. This produces zig-zag orbits $z_n:=(x_n,y_n)$ for which  $z_n/\|z_n\|$ may accumulate to both $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.

**Construction.** Define some smooth, positive, decreasing functions $u(t)$ and $v(t)$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$u(x):={1\over (n!)^2}\quad\text{for $n$ even, and}\; n!+1\le x\le (n+2)!$$
and
$$v(x):={1\over (n!)^2}\quad\text{for $n$ odd, and}\; n!+1\le x\le (n+2)!$$

(so one has only to extend them smoothly for $x\le2$ and  between $n!$ and $n!+1$ to have them defined everywhere). As a consequence we have
$${v(x)\over u(x)}=\begin{cases}
n^{-2}  &\text{for $n$ odd, and }\; n!+1\le x\le (n+1)! \\
n^2 &\text{for $n>0$ even, and }\; n!+1\le x\le (n+1)! \\
\end{cases}$$
while
$$n^{-2}\le {v(x)\over u(x)}\le n^2 \quad \text{for any $n>0$ and }\; n! \le x\le n!+1 \ .$$

Note also that $u$  (respectively  $v$) has finite integral on any right-unbounded interval, because the contribute to the integral on any interval $[n!+1, (n+2)!+1]$ (for $n$ even, resp. odd) is bounded by $(n+2)!/(n!)^2=(n+2)(n+1)/n!$. Therefore we can consider the smooth, decreasing, strictly convex functions
$$\phi(x):=\int_x^\infty u(t)dt\quad\text{and }\quad \psi(x):=\int_x^\infty v(t)dt\; .$$

The negative gradient iteration  $u_{n+1}=u_n-\eta\nabla f(u_n)$ writes, with $z_n:=(x_n,y_n)$
$$
\begin{cases}
x_{n+1}=x_n+\eta \,u(x_n) \\
y_{n+1}=y_n+\eta \,v(y_n)\\
\end{cases}
$$
and it follows from the above identities and inequalities  on $v/u$ that it produces sequences $(x_n,y_n)$ with $\liminf_{n\to+\infty}y_n/x_n=0$ and $\limsup_{n\to+\infty}y_n/x_n=+\infty$,
corresponding to a sequence $z_n/\|z_n\|$ that clusters both to $(1,0)$ and to $(0,1)$.

**Sketch of the computation.** Both sequences $x_m=x_0+\eta\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}u(x_j)$ and $y_m=x_0+\eta\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}v(y_j)$ are increasing and diverging. 
Let's define  $\mu(t)$ as  the largest integer $j$ such that $x_j\le n!$ and 
$\nu(t)$ as  the largest integer $j$ such that $y_j\le n!$. The point is to use the above identities and inequalities on $u$ and $v$ to show that, for even $n$ and $m=\mu(n!)$,  the principal part in both the above sum is given by the indices $j$ such that $\mu(n!)\le j\le \mu((n+1)!)$, so that $y_m/x_m=O(1/n^2)$. Analogously, for odd $n$ and $m=\nu(n!)$, one should get $x_m/y_m=O(1/n^2)$.

Comment: Thanks! It is not clear to me why such $\phi,\psi$ (or $u,v$) exist (or how to find them), and why the inequalities imply the result in the end.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should add more details.

Comment: Thanks, very nice! I wonder if there are some additional ("light") assumptions which one can add to $f$ so that $x_n/||x_n||$ would converge. Maybe that the Jacobian has a bounded eigenvalue ratio?

Comment: Good question and nice conjecture!

Comment: If it is good question, then perhaps it should also be on MO. So here it is:
https://mathoverflow.net/q/282934/44790

Comment: PS: I think a  variant that makes the computation simpler should be, replacing the sequence $n!$ with a generic strictly increasing diverging sequence $r(n)$. Then $y_n/x_n$ can be made arbitrarily close to $0$ and to $+\infty$ along subsequences, just defining $r(n)$ suitably, by induction.

Comment: I just noticed a small issue: the function $f$ you defined is not analytic (in $C^{\infty}$, as required in the question. Explanation: since $u$ and $v$ are not globally constant yet are constant on open non-empty segments, they cannot be analytic; therefore their integral is also not analytic. However, I think this could be corrected though, right?

Comment: Where in the question, or in the answer, it is mentioned analicity? The functions here are *smooth, i.e. $C^\infty$*. No obstruction to make them locally constant in some interval as required.

Comment: Ah, yes, these concepts are not the same. Sorry, I was confused. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: But if you want an analytic counterexample, you can approximate $u$ and $v$ with decreasing real analytic functions $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ in such a way that their ratio at any $x$ stays between half and twice the ratio of $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ (apply  to $u'$ and $v'$ Carleman's theorem quoted here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26243/asymptotic-approximation-of-x-alpha-by-entire-functions/26290#26290). Also, you can build directly $u$ and $v$ as entire functions by means of  conveniently defined  lacunary series.