# Asymptotic behavior of gradient descent on a smooth, convex, non-negative function with no finite minimum - part II

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, asymptotics, convex-optimization

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be a  function which is convex and smooth (*i.e.*, in $C^{\infty}$). If $x^* \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is the (global) minimum of $f$, it is [well known](https://rkganti.wordpress.com/2015/08/21/convergence-rate-of-gradient-descent-algorithm/) that gradient descent with a (sufficiently small) fixed step size $\eta$,
$$ x_{n+1} = x_{n} - \eta \nabla f(x_n), $$
converges to the global minimum $x_n \rightarrow x^*$.

When a finite minimizer $x^*$ does not exist (*i.e.*, when $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^d : \nabla f(x)\neq 0$), one might expect that $x_n/||x_n||$ should converge to a finite solution. However, there are [counterexamples](https://mathoverflow.net/q/282590/44790) to this claim.

**Question**: What additional assumptions (as "light" as possible) do we need to add to have on $f$ so that $x_n/||x_n||$ would converge (for a sufficiently small $\eta$)? The counterexample above suggests that the Hessian of $f$ perhaps should have a bounded eigenvalue ratio. Is this enough?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the "hessian" should have a bounded eigenvalue ratio, right? This is definitely a sufficient condition as it implies that the function is then strongly convex and thus have a unique global minimizer. So your gradient descend will converge to this solution.

Comment: Yes, 'Hessian' would be clearer here, corrected. I don't think it is this easy though. The Hessian can vanish to zero at infinity, yet the ratio can remain bounded.

Comment: I think you may need to require $f$ to be a $C^1$ semi-algebraic function.